# How can I make vim autocomplete on :e and :tabnew skip .class files?

Tags: vim

In particular, suppose I am in a directory with Foo.java, Foo.class, Bar.java, and Bar.class.

Suppose I have vim open on Foo.java, and I want to go to Bar.java.

The natural thing for me is to type `:e B<Tab>`. 
However, this will always complete to Bar.class before Bar.java.

Is there a way I can make the auto-complete ignore the class file?

Comment: never use vim's default openings. god, never do that. use ctrlp.vim https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim and see g:ctrlp_custom_ignore

Comment: Mainly because of the overall awesomeness of ctrlp. It really is worth getting to know.

Comment: because you're wasting your time using vim's archaic functionality. plugins that make vim act more like a good editor (in this case, for files, ctrlp or lusty juggler) are 100 times better than the mess that we have left behind from 40 years ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [wildignore](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27wildignore%27):

```
set wildignore=*.class
```